# Seeking Story Map tutorials?

Tags: references, story-map

I am fairly new to ArcGIS and just wanted to know if anyone knew of any particularly helpful tutorials online or books for making story maps?

Comment: Have you visited [Apps page](http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/) of the Esri Story Map site? Most of the different templates have a step-by-step guide on how to create one (like [this](http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-tour/tutorial/) for the Map Tour template)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the a detailed walk through provided by Esri on [how to make a story map](http://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/how-to/). Within this site you can navigate around to find different templates and application types with instructions on how to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

[Making Family HiStory Maps using ArcGIS Online](http://discoverspatial.com/p/making-family-history-maps-using-arcgis-online) is an eLearning video tutorial that teaches you how to use a Story Map Journal (with Flickr for storing images) for sharing genealogy.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author and presenter of this eLearning video tutorial